# Passar de JFrame para JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Criei um frame deste gênero:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas,visto que era para apresentar que o cliente estava com  problema ao conectar com um servidor, foi melhor passar para JDialog

Problema:
Não consigo que o JDialog fique visível

Código:

```
public class WaitingJoption extends JDialog { //se for JFrame funciona direito

    public WaitingJoption() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setTitle("Agurde pff...");
        setUndecorated(true);
        JPanel pane= new JPanel();
        JPanel pane1= new JPanel();

        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        pane1 = new Surface();

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.ipady = 80;      //make this component tall
        c.ipadx = 80;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(pane1, c);


        JLabel labe = new JLabel("O cliente está a tentar connectar com o servidor...");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(labe, c);


        getContentPane().add(pane);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                WaitingJoption wt = new WaitingJoption();
                wt.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: O melhor seria utilizar um JDialog para isto e evitar ter vários JFrame em seu programa. Aliás, com JDialog você pode tornar o componente modal, evitando que o usuário tente acessar outra funcionalidade do programa enquanto está tentando reconectar.

Comment: Já tentei implementar essa ideia mas não consegui por a funcionar... Não dá nenhum erro mas também nao consigo por a funcionar, vou postar código...

Comment: Eu testei aqui e foi lançada uma Exception na linha 50. Você está usando a constante `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` (que é para componentes JFrame) em um JDialog. Experimente mudar para  `setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: Era mesmo isso, não sei porque é que no meu não lança essa excepção, cria uma resposta com isso para poder marcar como certa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No código em questão é lançada uma `IllegalArgumentException` na linha 50.

Isto ocorre porque você está usando uma constante ilegal para um `JDialog` no seguinte trecho:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

As constantes que podem ser utilizadas nesse método para `JDialog` são: `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`, or `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`. Altere para:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

[Referência: WindowConstants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html)